# Scheduled Cron Job in Mac Local for all the IP Addresses I have been associated with

Tags: macos, cron

I want to write a scheduled job which will log my External IP address into a text file every minute.
I used CRONTAB to write this.

```
* * * * * ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1 >> myipaddresses.txt
```

This should execute every minute and log my ip address in a file called myipaddresses.txt.

Somehow, my cronjob ran as expected for some few minutes.
Once I restarted my system, it stopped working and it does not start to work even if I edited and re started the CRON Job.

I am ok to move away from CRON and use Automator or something like that.

Comment: I'm not sure why it failed, but the Mac way to run repeating jobs is with `launchd`.

Comment: Neither am I! Could you please help me write a similar job in launchd? I haven't used it at all.  Thanks,

Comment: Read the documentation, give it a try, and then come back. Actually, apple.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place to post. If you search there, you can probably find examples of what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Much helpful. Appreciate it.